# What are the settings and syntax for creating a Databricks table referencing data that already exists on Azure ADLS?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I'm struggling with running a CREATE TABLE statement on Databricks that will point to a folder on Azure ADLS with data already in it.

Assuming this is the path and the account is already mounted: `/mnt/my_container/path/to/folder/datafile.parquet`

There are multiple parquet files in that folder.

I've tried running variations of this, but I don't know what else to add:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_metastore.schema.table_name (
field1 STRING,
field2 INT
)
USING DELTA
LOCATION 'dbfs:/mnt/my_container/path/to/folder/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.minReaderVersion' = '1', 'delta.minWriterVersion' = '2', 'upgraded_to' = '`stage_db`.`schema`.`table_name_temp`')
```

I was told to use that entire `TBLPROPERTIES` parameter. Is there anything incorrect about this?

Answer (score 0):

For example, I used a parquet file in my ADLS.

I added the **TBLPROPERTIES** clause with the specified properties.
The `delta.minReaderVersion` and `delta.minWriterVersion` properties control the Delta format version compatibility.
The `upgraded_to` property is typically used during schema evolution to track the table upgrade history.

I tried the approach below:

```
adls_file_path = "abfss://folder02@dileepstggen2.dfs.core.windows.net/movies_delta"
table_name = "movies_table"
spark.sql(f"""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name}
    USING DELTA
    LOCATION '{adls_file_path}'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
        'delta.minReaderVersion' = '1',
        'delta.minWriterVersion' = '2',
        'upgraded_to' = '`stage_db`.`schema`.`table_name_temp`'
    )
""")
```

[image]

[image]

I also created a table using the parquet format:

```
adls_file_path = "abfss://folder02@dileepstggen2.dfs.core.windows.net/movies.parquet"
table_name = "movies_table"
spark.sql(f"""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name}
    USING PARQUET
    OPTIONS (
        'path' = '{adls_file_path}'
    )
""")
```